# Concatenate Column and value as property To existing JSON object in another column In SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, sql-server-2016

Let's say I have the following table Product

[image]

Comment: are you using a programming environment or it's pure sql ?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 doesn't understand JSON. JSON support was added in SQL Server 2016. SQL Server 2012 is out of support too, and 10 years old at this point. All SQL Server versions still in mainstream support can modify JSON data [as the docs show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#example---multiple-updates). Withoug JSON_MODIFY it would be better to make such modifications on the client. Adding two properties to a nested object goes beyond the very simple string manipulation functions offered by SQL Server 2012

Comment: As of now I wanted to get this done in SQL.

Comment: If you want to do this in SQL, upgrade to a supported SQL Server version and use `JSON_MODIFY`. You can't do what you want in a safe way with simple string replacements. SQL Server 2012 doesn't even have `STRING_SPLIT`. While you could delete the last 3 characters of the string, and append ` '"ProductID":"' + ProductId + '"}]}"`, what happens if there are multiple objects? What if there are multiple top-level properties? What if you miss a double quote? You'd end up with mangled data, or properties added to the wrong object

Comment: currently I am using SSMS V18.9.1

Comment: You could use a SQLCLR function to parse and modify the JSON text *BUT* - SQL Server 2012 didn't support .NET Framework 4.x. In .NET Framework 3.5 you'd have to either use .NET's obsolete JavascriptSerializer that couldn't even format dates correctly, or use a very old version of JSON.NET

Comment: SSMS is the client tool, not SQL Server. It doesn't change how SQL Server works or what features are supported

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually this requirement is for my C# API. I thought this will be easier through SQL. I wrote API using .Net Core 2.2 and getting list data, and not sure how to get this done through API for my requirement. any inputs?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Please post your questions, including data, as text. Images are not searchable content. Typing a question into Word and screenshotting it is working against the very spirit of StackOverflow, which is to provide a searchable source of questions and answers to assist the development community.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested `FOR JSON` subquery, which breaks open the original JSON using `OPENJSON` and re-aggregates it

```sql
SELECT
  p.ProductID,
  p.ProductName,
  (
      SELECT
        p.ProductID,
        p.ProductName,
        j.Price,
        j.Shipper
      FROM OPENJSON(p.Results, '$.Results')
        WITH (
            Price int,
            Shipper varchar(100)
        ) j
      FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Results')
  ) AS Results
FROM Product p;
```